# Encontrando usuários por região

Tags: suporte, contas-usuário, busca

Sou novo o StackOverflow Português, mas já estou há um bom tempo no Mathematica StackExchange. Enfim, lá sei que existem muitos brasileiros que usam o Mathematica e encontrei muitos por acaso.
Existe uma ferramenta que FILTRE os usuários por localidade? Pelo menos aqueles que tem em seu perfil o local como o meu?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já agora, bem-vindo!

Comment: Muito interessante a tua pergunta.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apenas para exemplificar a [resposta do @rray](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5569/20615), faça os seguintes passos:

#### Acesse [este link](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/revision/606720/758164/usuarios-por-localidade) do Data.SE;

- 1 Digite a localidade desejada;
- 2 Clique em **Run Query**;
- 3 Aguarde.

Veja a imagem abaixo para seguir os passos acima.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Que legal! Funcionou perfeitamente. Não tenho noção nenhuma neste tipo de programação. Obrigado.

Comment: E outra coisa... Estava cansado de conversar só com gringo... :)

Answer (score 12):

Pelo [data exchange](http://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/new) é possível fazer isso, desde que o usuário tenha a cidade/estado/local no perfil

A consulta seria mais ou menos assim:

```
SELECT displayname, location FROM users WHERE LOWER(location) like LOWER('%cidade/pais%')
```

Na hora de buscar o termo fique atento para a grafia alguns estão em inglês como Brazil ou outros (colocado manualmente) como Brasil.

Comment: Muito bom. Mas desculpe a ignorância, o que eu preciso fazer para definir `Brasil`? Ou é só entrar neste site e colar exatamente o que você postou?

Comment: @LCarvalho editei a resposta é só trocar `cidade/pais` pelo termo desejado agora a comparação é feita em caixa baixa já que Brasil é diferente de brasil.