# Encontrando "UPVoters"

Tags: debate

Há pouco tempo eu perguntei como encontrar usuários de [certa localidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5568/encontrando-usu%C3%A1rios)

Agora estou curioso pra saber como criar uma lista dos usuários que deram UPVOTE ou DOWNVOTE em minhas questões ou respostas.

Comment: Propositalmente essa informação não está disponível. Até já houve um debate superficial sobre a possibilidade do voto ser aberto, mas a ideia geral é que há mais malefícios que benefícios em deixar os votos expostos.

Comment: Isso vai ser difícil LCarvalho. O sistema todo do SO é construído em cima de votos anonimos. Tentar reconstruir quem votou como a partir dos dados do  SO é um exercício interessante (valendo um emprego como cientista de dados na NSA).

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Estava acabando de ler a este respeito sobre anonimato. Que bom que tirou minha dúvida...

Comment: De vez em quando já rola uns desentendimentos por causa de voto, com ele sendo secreto, imagina se fosse público? hehehe

Comment: @diegofm Acho que acontece mais aqui em Português. No site em inglês é meio raro.

Comment: Esse é um assunto muito interessante. Acredito que sendo aberto accaretaria em muitas discussões, porém o SO deveria dar uma atenção especial a esse assunto, pois existem muitos downvoters que simplesmente dão o voto e não ajudam em nada.

Qual a utilidade de eu chegar no meu post e ver que levei 3 downvotes e não saber o pq? Irá me fazer pensar sobre a questão porém como foi eu mesmo que escrevi, no meu pensamento estará suficiente para entendimento.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Os votos são mantidos secretos propositadamente. O sistema foi projetado assim desde o princípio, e a ideia é evitar que as pessoas gastem foco e energia avaliando padrões de votos, ao invés de se concentrarem em boas perguntas e repostas.

Como curiosidade: o princípio de anonimato dos votos é tão forte que *nem eu* tenho acesso "imediato" aos votos nos meus posts, apesar de conseguir ver todos os votos dados nos outros posts com 1 clique. Pra ver votos nos meus posts eu preciso me dar ao trabalho de ir buscar no banco de dados. E, francamente, nunca vale a pena.

Comment: então esse anonimato é relativo ? Qual o sentido de apenas alguns membros poderem ter acesso a esse tipo de informação ?

Comment: @MagicHat, alguns membros = Funcionários da Stack Overflow. Uma vez que você tenha acesso ao banco de dados não vejo propósito em tentar esconder isso na aplicação. A relação usuário / voto tem que estar registrada para reverter votos em massa, possibilitar auditoria, etc.

Comment: @MagicHat Como o AnthonyAccioly adiantou, como funcionário e gerente de comunidades, eu preciso ter acesso à essa informação, tanto aqui quanto em todos os outros sites, pra facilitar meu trabalho quando ele envolve manipulação de votos, acusações no Meta ou às vezes até bugs.

Comment: sim, compreendo é como foi projetado, e certas coisas são necessárias.

Comment: "*apesar de conseguir ver todos os votos dados nos outros posts com 1 clique*" - Você está dizendo que você tem acesso às informações de quem votou no que (exceto se você estiver envolvido) com apenas um clique? Imaginava que o processo fosse um pouco mais burocrático.

Comment: @VictorStafusa um pouco mais burocrático ia tornar meu trabalho exponencialmente mais difícil, quando preciso avaliar certas coisas

Comment: @VictorStafusa vale relembrar que os mods não possuem esse poder, só os funcionários do SO

Comment: @Math, sim eu sei. Eu imaginava que nesses casos o Shog9 ou algum outro funcionário da SE tinha que rodar alguma query no banco de dados ou no data explorer para obter esses tipos de informações.